# Adaptive card not rendering in WebChat

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, adaptive-cards

I want to use adaptive card in my BDK v4 to use dropdown list. Just for sample I created a TextBlock to display a adaptive card in webchat. When I tested in Bot emulator adaptive card displaying fine. When I deployed the code adaptive card is not rendering in Webchat.

Can Anyone help on this please ?

```
Attachment skillRecommendationAttachment = new Attachment();
Activity replyToActivity = innerDc.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
skillRecommendationAttachment = GetSkillsCardAttachment();
Attachment GetSkillsCardAttachment()
{
    AdaptiveCard card = new AdaptiveCard("1.0");
    card.Version = "1.0";
    card.Type = "AdaptiveCard";
    card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
    {
       Text = "NEAR SKILLS",
       Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Large,
       Weight = AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
    });

    Attachment attachment = new Attachment()
    {
       ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
       Content = card
     };

     return attachment;
}

replyToActivity.Attachments.Add(skillRecommendationAttachment);
await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync(replyToActivity);
```

It's displaying as below
[image: Output in webchat]

Help me here how can i get adaptive card?

Comment: That's no ordinary Web Chat. You're using a custom Direct Line client that doesn't have an Adaptive Card renderer I'm guessing. Can you provide your client code?

Comment: Are you still working on this?